# What makes this question about c# v6.0 safe navigation operator too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

This is not a complaining question :)

I asked what I thought to be a pretty specific question:

> #### [How does the ?. (Safe Navigation Operator) work in c# 6.0 (VS 2015 CTP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354321/how-does-the-safe-navigation-operator-work-in-c-sharp-6-0-vs-2015-ctp)
>
> Currently there is no Safe Navigation Operator (?.) for C#. You have
> to do something like this.
> [Safe Navigation Operator in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110659/safe-navigation-operator-in-c)
>
> According to
> [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jerrynixon/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator) blog post and [this](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883)
> post. C# 6.0 might be getting a safe navigation operator.
>
> Apparently, this new language functionality should exist in the VS2015
> CTP.
> [source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/880467/What-is-Cool-about-Csharp)
>
> The syntax is pretty easy to understand
>
> ```
> var result = Obj1?.obj2?.obj3?.obj4.thing;
> ```
>
> At any point objects 1, 2, 3, or 4 could be null which makes 'result'
> null. It eliminates having to write code for a bunch of null checks.
>
> Specifically, how does the compiler accomplish this?
>
> A simple solution I can think of would be to generate a bunch of 'if'
> statements for each object, but that may be considered 'sloppy' by
> some. Does anyone now how the compiler actually does it?

It was closed as too broad. In my mind I envisioned this question as answerable by writing some code with the "?." operator in C# 6 in the VS2015 CTP and inspecting the IDL.

One of the comments on the question even suggested that I do it myself. Very possible, right?

I'm probably missing something. I'm not offended that the question was closed, but would like some clarification since the folks who voted to close the question and delete it didn't offer any comments.

I could possibly see an argument for a duplicate question, but even then I tried direct the question towards the behavior of the compiler which weren't the thrust of similar "what is the ?. operator in C#" types of questions.

Comment: So, I think I'm missing why you didn't try it yourself. I would have voted it down for "does not show any research effort" for just such behavior.

Comment: @Qantas How did you manage to get the question, being <10k?

Comment: @Joe - RE: <10k? http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:fBsKFBLivloJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/29354321/how-does-the-safe-navigation-operator-work-in-c-sharp-6-0-vs-2015-ctp+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: @joe google cache have it...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't have VS2015 CTP readily available to test with. The research effort is there showing that it should exist in vs2015. It's pretty safe to assume that someone in the community has probably played around with it more than I have. There is research effort in the question. I think you would have down voted the question for not attempting to answer the question myself.

Answer (score 8):

> One of the comments on the question even suggested that I do it myself. Very possible, right?

Yes, that is *very* possible.  I suspect that's at least one reason for the close votes.  You probably got more by calling it "IDL", proper term is IL.  And final nail in the coffin is that you are asking questions about a beta version of Visual Studio, lots of SO users in the C# tag don't have that version yet.  Which makes the question hard to answer and answers liable to be incorrect when VS2015 is released.

So just bide your time, it won't be long before that happens.  Probably somewhere in the summer.

And you don't have to wait asking a question about how you can "do it yourself", you can ask it now.  Be sure to research it first!  Google "c# il".  After having read the hits and existing SO answers you probably don't have to ask the question anymore.  And if you still do then it won't be "too broad".

Comment: OK. I suppose that makes sense. I thought there might have been a Visual Studio fan out there who is up to date on all the latest and greatest that might jump on the question. I can also understand the "you're asking about a beta VS" argument making answers liable to be incorrect. I had edited the question to be specifically about the CTP version... but I guess a different version of the CTP could also be released making answers liable to be incorrect. So, point taken.